# parallel install ncurses-6 & ncurses-5 on fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, ncurses, dnf

I just upgraded from `fedora` 23 to 24, and it broke some binaries I have on my system that were not installed from fedora's repositories, due to the `ncurses` upgrade from version 5 to version 6:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I wonder whether it's possible to install in parallel ncurses5 & 6 on fedora 24 so I can keep using these binaries? After all that would be the whole point of having these version postfixes, parallel installation right? But I don't see a ncurses5 fedora 24 package...? So.. is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

Please always use a file search : # `dnf provides */libtinfo.so.5`

.... and the reply is `ncurses-compat-libs-6.0`

Install : # `dnf install ncurses-compat-libs`

---

---

Comment: `apt-get install ncurses-compat-libs` and `yum install ncurses-compat-libs` both work on other distros.