# How to Install ncurses-devel version 5 on Fedora 26?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, fedora

I am building android for NXP I.MX6 on Fedora 26, after doing lunch (many times, every time), I get following error:

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed **ncurses-devel** and **ncurses-compat-libs** as suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1093042/parallel-install-ncurses-6-ncurses-5-on-fedora-24) link, but still it throws the above error.

On investigation, I understand that ncurses-devel installs version 6 by default and I suspect ncurses-compat-libs installs only 32-bit libraries for version 5 & 6.

**32-bit library path**:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libncurses*
libncurses.so         libncurses.so.5.9     libncurses.so.6.0    libncurses++w.so.5    libncurses++w.so.6    
libncurses++.so       libncurses++.so.5.9   libncurses++.so.6.0   libncursesw.so.5      libncursesw.so.6      
libncurses.so.5       libncurses.so.6       libncurses++w.so      libncurses++w.so.5.9  libncurses++w.so.6.0  
libncurses++.so.5     libncurses++.so.6     libncursesw.so        libncursesw.so.5.9    libncursesw.so.6.0
```

**64-bit library path**:

```
$ ls /usr/lib64/libncurses*
/usr/lib64/libncurses.so    /usr/lib64/libncurses++.so.6    /usr/lib64  /libncurses++w.so    /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6
/usr/lib64/libncurses++.so  /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6.0    /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so      /usr/lib64/libncurses++w.so.6.0
/usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6  /usr/lib64/libncurses++.so.6.0  /usr/lib64/libncurses++w.so.6  /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.0
```

So the question is how do I install **ncursed-devel version 5** on Fedora 26?

Comment: Is there a reason why it can't use the system clang?

Comment: There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ncurses-compat-libs, but no development headers because (mentioned in a bug report...) that there's no reason to support *development* using ABI 5.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I guess it is because Android uses pre-built toolchains but expects compatible libraries available on the host machine.